# sql query to check data present in given range and data not present in given range

Tags: sql-server, between

I have a table demo in which current column is present.I want a sql query which displays data where current is between range 10 and 90 and current values  which are not present in the range near 30 and 40 through a single sql query.

Comment: what about `BETWEEN` ? Did you tried anything ?

Comment: I tried between and I get the result for between '10' and '90'.But can't understand how to specify not between '30' and '40'??

Comment: Post your query so far that isn't working. The answer will probably be something with a few where clauses eg `WHERE (x BETWEEN 10 AND 30) OR (x BETWEEN 40 AND 90)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT BETWEEN`. Refer [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SQLServer/0020__Query/NOTBETWEEN.htm)

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE Column NOT BETWEEN 30 and 40 
      AND Column BETWEEN 10 AND 90
```

Answer (score 1):

www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php

Refer this article.

With case you can achieve you answer. No need of using between clause.